# Extend AssetLinksGenerator.GenerateLinks to serve .gz files

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, performance-optimization, gzip

My site is performing very slow. Google Page Speed suggests to use a few optimization algorithms, one of them is `GZip`. I have created some theme assets using this algorithm and imported my theme. Now I want to refer those files from my layout file. Existing code for getting these assets is as below

```
AssetLinks assetLinks = AssetLinksGenerator.GenerateLinks(new ThemesProvider());
```

but this provides me only `js` and `css` file. GZip algorithm created `.gz` files. Is there anyway to get other files like `.gz` from the theme, or do I need to customize something? Is there any place where I can feed these files to be picked up by `AssetLinksGenerator`?

Comment: That's not quite how GZip works on a web server. Have you enabled dynamic compression either in IIS or your `web.config`? Some info for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654301/sitecore-mvc-gzip-compression-error - https://bala.one/spice-up-sitecore-performance-with-iis/ - https://bartlomiejmucha.com/en/blog/simple-techniques-to-improve-site-performance/

Comment: @RichardSeal thanks for these links. Yes, we have dynamic compression enabled in prod.

Comment: So you don't need to gzip the theme files and serve them via Sitecore. The server does the compression and the browser decompresses.

Comment: @RichardSeal there is a css file, it's size on disk is ~380KB, when served from local IIS (without dynamic compression) it is  ~390KB, when served from Prod IIS(with dynamic compression) it is ~170KB. When I used npm build with webpack and Gzip plugin I got .gz file with size of ~65KB. I thought if npm is compression file so well then may be I can upload it and get this level of compression. What I am unable to understand is, if IIS using gzip when dynamic compression is set, why it is serving larger size than one created by npm

Comment: Because IIS GZip is not the same thing as zipping the file locally.